# How to compare rectangles and find similar?

Tags: python, list, numpy

I have code

```
c = collections.Counter(l)
print(c)
```

The results are several of rectangles

> ((x,y,w,h), amount of rectangles in list),

```
[
((1808, 1022, 21, 15), 19), 
((1671, 1019, 42, 44), 18), 
((1808, 1022, 21, 16), 14), 
((1848, 1022, 21, 15), 13), 
((1671, 1017, 42, 46), 13), 
((1848, 1022, 21, 16), 11), 
((1808, 1021, 21, 16), 10), 
((1808, 1021, 21, 17), 4)]
```

I want to find all similar rectangles and combine them as one average rectangle.

Under similarity I mean this condition:    x +-  3%  and y +- 3% and w +- 3% and h +- 3%

For, example we find

the first group of the similar rectangles

```
((1808, 1022, 21, 15), 19),     
((1808, 1022, 21, 16), 14), 
((1848, 1022, 21, 15), 13),    
((1848, 1022, 21, 16), 11), 
((1808, 1021, 21, 16), 10), 
((1808, 1021, 21, 17), 4)
```

and the second group

```
((1671, 1019, 42, 44), 18), 
((1671, 1017, 42, 46), 13),
```

Calculate average values (x,y,w,h) and sum number of rectangles and this the result I want

```
 [
   ((1671, 1018, 42, 45), 31), 
   ((1825, 1022, 21, 16), 71)
 ]
```

Comment: This is a little underspecified. What have you tried to solve your problem and what specific challenges have you encountered?

Comment: Similarity to within 3% is not in general an equivalence relation (it fails to be transitive) but the way that you phrased the question seems to assume that it is. You could look into clustering algorithms.

Comment: It isn't clear what you mean by "similarity". Mathematically, two rectangles are similar if and only if the ratios of their longer sides to their shorter sizes are equal. This is a condition on `h` and `w` alone -- but you mention `x,y` as well. So, what exactly are you talking about?

Comment: @John Coleman, sorry.  Under similarity I mean this condition   'x +- 3% and y +- 3% and w +- 3% and h +- 3%'

Comment: @Iguananaut , I edit question. I want the result:  [
   ((1671, 1018, 42, 45), 31), 
   ((1825, 1022, 21, 16), 71)
 ]

Comment: Yes but you didn't explain by what logic you arrived at that result. No one is likely going to want to take the time to reverse engineer the logic in your head. Now it seems you've added a little bit more, but you also seem to have some concept of grouping which is unclear too (e.g. what if the same rectangle is in two different groups based on this similarity condition?)